# Semaphore for CMD instances working in Parallel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have .bat that would be started X times (with different arguments) at the same moment.

Ideally I would need mechanism that would allow only one bat to lock the file and process it as long as it's needed than release it allowing same thing for another process.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think the question is pretty clear (and interesting as well)

Comment: He/she wants to serialize the access to a single file from multiple batch files. What's unclear about "*I would like them to modify one specific file but it has to be done in sequence*"

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of processes that need to modify the file?  Do they always need to run in the same order (sequence)?  Is the number of process always the same?  I have a few ideas -- but your answers will make a lot of difference which way the solution goes...

Comment: I forgot I had this account, removed a line that was not written very well/confusing. 
I used solution from dbenham, back then and it worked great, I wish I remembered what it was for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few improvements to jeb's answer.

There is no need for an extra lock file. The queue.txt file can serve as its own lock.

Also, the innermost block must be guaranteed to exit with SUCCESS (errorlevel 0) so that the retry only occurs when the redirection failed. `(CALL )` (note the trailing space) is a totally non-intuitive, yet extremely efficient way to clear any error. Not needed here, but `(CALL)` (note the lack of space) is an efficient way to set an error.

```
:lockedAppend
2>nul (
  >>queue.txt (
    REM Do any amount of processing within this block.
    REM All stdout will safely be appended to the queue
    REM You could even call out to a subroutine, or another batch file

    echo Any text you want

    REM The CALL below ensures that the block exits with ERRORLEVEL 0 - success
    (call )
  )
)||goto :lockedAppend
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with a file lock, described by dbenham at [Dostips: parallel process with batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=12454) and [SO: How do you have shared log files under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344547/463115).

As windows locks a file when a write handle is opened, each other try to access the file will result in an error.

The first process can access the file and write to it, the second process fails to open it and will loop until the first process has finished.

```
:lockedAppend
2>nul (
  >queue.lock (
    >>queue.txt echo All text I want
  )
)||goto :lockedAppend
```

Comment: +1, but there is room for improvement. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621508/1012053)