# 2 individual command lines with same realtime variable

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 command lines and I need  the variables to be the same in both command lines.

For example:

command line 1:

```
set testvar=this does not work

For /l %%a in (0 0 1) do echo %testvar%
```

command line 2:

```
set testvar=this works
```

Command line 1 is started first.
The result of the 2nd command line should be "this does not work" multiple times in a row until I open the 2nd command line, then it should change to "this works" multiple times in a row.

I have tried a lot of different methods, for example storing the variable in a file on the harddisk but this isn't fast enough, i has to be memory based. The setx command is also not fast enough.

If anyone knows a solution pleas tell me.

Comment: [Here is an article on IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) Not all methods are applicable to batch, but if speed is an issue bath might  not be the best choice anyway.

Comment: @LotPings: I'd say none of those things are applicable to batch files (without resorting to external non-standard software at least).

Comment: To synchronise two `cmd` instances you might be interested in the [`waitfor` command](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html)...

Comment: @Joey Well agreed, that wasn't a clever way to point beyond one's own nose

Comment: @aschipfl I had already looked up [Semaphore for CMD instances working in Parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618595) for that purpose. Don't know which method is more efficiently.

Comment: @aschipfl: Wow, didn't know about that one yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access process memory of a different process from a batch file (and even with actual programming languages you usually shouldn't, but then there are better synchronization primitives anyway). `setx` cannot work because it simply changes the registry and thus only affects *new* processes, not already existing ones.

A file is actually your best bet in batch files. Have you actually tried whether it's fast enough (files are still backed by memory, so creating a file and reading it should not incur constant disk thrashing in this case)? Note that you probably *should* include some sort of sleeping (e.g. via `ping`) in your consuming batch file to avoid busy waiting.

If you're only interested in a single bit (looks like you are), then you can just check for existence of a file which is faster than reading it:

```
1.cmd
=====

for /l %%a in (0,0,1) do (
  if exist this.works (echo this works) else (echo this does not work)
  ping localhost -n 2 >nul 2>&1
)

2.cmd

copy nul this.works
```

Comment: `setx` coupled with `reg query` should do it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: In that case I'd rather use the registry directly instead of polluting environment variable defaults. Launching `reg` on a loop is likely to be slower than all other options, though.

Answer (score 1):

For me, without more information, files *"should"* be fast enough

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "flagFile=flagfile.txt"
    >"%flagFile%" type nul 

    if "%~1"=="second" goto :secondCopy
    start "" "%~f0" second

:firstCopy
    set /p "var=Input something: "
    >>"%flagFile%" echo !time! !var!
    goto :firstCopy

:secondCopy
    echo Waiting for data
    <"%flagFile%" (
        for /l %%a in (0 0 1) do (
            set /p "var=" && (
                echo !time! !var!
            )
        )
    )
```

This will allow you to compare the time difference between the write and the read time.