# Windows command line. Starting processes outside of existing queue

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

First please excuse my english :-)

SITUATION:

I'm using queued bat processes using code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618595/semaphore-for-cmd-instances-working-in-parallel)

Let's call it BAT1 - this file start minimized after droping a file to be processed onto it and launching pop-up window showing the actual processing - there can be several of these running and waiting for their chance to "jump in":

```
title Waiting
echo %1
:lockedAppend
timeout -t 10 /nobreak > NUL
2>nul (
   >>%userprofile%\queue.txt (
   title Working
   start /wait %userprofile%\Documents\BAT2.bat %1
   (call )
  )
)||goto :lockedAppend
```

BAT2 - contains code to process file droped on BAT1 passed by parameter. BAT2 ends with:

```
start /min BAT3.bat "%FileToArchive%"
exit
```

BAT2 is NOT waiting for BAT3 to finish before continuing or exiting in this case. BAT2 closes meaning BAT1 closes and queue should IMO be free for another BAT1 to jump in.

BUT! Frome reason that is escaping me none of waiting BAT1's runs before BAT3 finishes.

---

QUESTION:
Is there a way to run BAT3 being ignored by the queue code of BAT1?

Comment: You should probably `Call "%UserProfile%\Documents\BAT2.bat" "%~1"` instead of `start /wait %userprofile%\Documents\BAT2.bat %1`.

Comment: That does not make the pop-up window, instead the process runs in this minimized window directly and output is written in the lock file instead of screen.