# How do I make a batchscript that displays only the last line of a textfile?

Tags: windows, batch-file

this might have already been answered before but I couldn't find anything on that topic. Im trying to make a chat messenger in batch and for that I need to display the last line of a textfile. Here's what I tried (not very elegant):

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%x in (address.txt) DO set address=%%x
:A
IF NOT EXIST "%address%" GOTO A
GOTO B
:B
SET skipcount=1
:C
FOR /f "skip=%skipcount%" %%m in (%address%) DO ECHO %%m
SET m1=%%m
:D
FOR /f %%m IN (%address%) DO ECHO %%m > NUL
IF NOT %%m==%m1% SET skipcount=%skipcount%+1 GOTO D 
GOTO C
```

This might work but I think it is full of mistakes for example syntax errors^^ So I am just trying to get a few hints to what is wrong:)

Answer (score 2):

here's a [pure batch utility](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/fileUtils/tailHead.bat) (requires no external tools) that can shows a range of numbered lines

to show the last line use it like this:

```
call tailHead.bat -file=address.txt -end=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) to create a tail command. JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following command will show the last line in chat.txt

```
call jrepl "^.*" "" /match /inc -1 /f chat.txt
```

But there is a much better way to develop a batch chat program (assuming that is a worthwhile goal)

You can have a batch process in a loop, with input redirected outside the loop, and the loop will read and write newly added lines as they appear. You could use SET /P and ECHO, but it is simpler to use a single FINDSTR. This works because FINDSTR does not reset the file pointer when called, as explained at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9720#p9720.

You should use some command to suspend processing briefly within the display loop to prevent the loop from consuming 100% of a CPU core. You could use TIMEOUT, or the PING hack, but they introduce a ~1 second delay. I chose to use PATHPING to introduce a ~0.2 second delay.

Also, you must worry about preventing collisions if two processes write to the same text file simultaneously. This can be solved by using lock files, as explained at [How do you have shared log files under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9337415/1012053).

Below is the beginning of a rudimentary batch chat program. It works by having two or more users each navigate to the same shared directory, and then run `chat.bat sessionName`, where sessionName is an agreed upon name for the shared chat file. Each user will get the shared chat dialog displayed in their master console window, and a new console window will open where they can write their contributions to the conversation. Enter `:quit` to exit the chat program.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" equ ":input" goto :startInput
if "%~1" equ ":display" goto :display
set "base=%~1"
set "dialog=%base%.chat"
set "quitfile=%base%_%username%.chat.quit"
start "" "%~f0" :input
del "%quitfile%" 2>nul
cmd /c "%~f0" :display
del "%quitfile%" 2>nul
exit /b


:display
title Chat Dialog
set "quit="
if not exist "%dialog%" (call ) >>"%dialog%"

<"%dialog%" (  for /l %%N in () do (
  if exist "%quitfile%" set "quit=1"
  findstr "^"
  if defined quit exit
  pathping -p 150 -q 2 localhost >nul
))

:startInput
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
title Chat Input
call :write ">>> %username% has joined the conversation"
:input
cls
set "text="
set /p "text=>"
if /i !text! equ :quit (
  call :write "<<< %username% has left the conversation"
  copy nul "!quitfile!"
  exit
)
call :write
goto :input


:write
if "%~1" neq "" (set "text=%~1") else (set "text=%username%: !text!")
2>nul (
  >>"!dialog!" (
    echo(!text!
    (call )
  ) || goto :write
)
exit /b
```

Still to be done:

- Provide a mechanism to invite users to a chat.
- Provide an option to clear chat contents at the beginning of a new chat session (in case an old sessionName is reused)
- Provide a :list command to list the currently participating users. This would require creation of sessionNameUserId files that would remain locked as long as the user is still listening and/or participating. The display loop could receive a :list command via a file, the same way as I implemented :quit, and then it could attempt to open each sessionNameuserID file for writing. If it fails then the user is still active, and the name should be listed.
- I'm sure there are other things that might be useful.