# how to detect change in .txt file using batch?

Tags: file, batch-file, updates

I made a simple LAN chat batch file, and i would like to know if
there is an command that checks if a specific txt file is updated.
The chat history is stored in log.dat and i want to have a sound notification or something like that when theres a new message.

```
@echo off
title LAN chat reader
call Color.bat

:read
call Color.bat
cls
type log.dat
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto read
```

(im a noob, please tell me if this is possible)

Comment: This is a really crazy idea(a batch), but i like it thumbs up. :)

Comment: You will not have a very effective chat program with the design you are pursuing. I have posted a rudimentary but effective chat batch script at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29967710/1012053. Each user gets two command windows - one where the user types messages, and the other where all new messages from all sources are displayed, each with a userName: prefix.

Comment: I have a similar chat thing. 2 widows for reading/sending and one for the operator with admin options (such as color: saved in color.bat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the file date/time use `for` and `%%~t` prefix:

```
@echo off
title LAN chat reader
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:read
    call Color.bat
    cls
    type log.dat

    for %%a in (log.dat) do set filetimesize=%%~tza
    :checkupdate
        ping -n 1 -w 100 localhost >nul
        for %%a in (log.dat) do if "!filetimesize!"=="%%~tza" goto checkupdate
    echo updated
    goto read
```

Comment: I tried this, but the window would shut instantly
(im using an MP3-file instead of !FILENAME! is that the problem?

Comment: 1. What is a `!FILENAME!`? 2. Do the standard thing: remove `@echo off` and run the batch file from a Command Prompt console to actually see what's wrong.

Comment: sorry, forget about    !FILENAME!
I got this output:
=%~ta not expected at this moment.

Comment: ok, i used the updated code, but ran into 2 problems:
1 It wil only update once, then i have to restart it to see the newest chat messages.
2 Wheres the output? like "start example.mp3"
(probaly stupid questions, but im not advanced at all)

Comment: Updated the code. The time string had no seconds so I've added the file size into comparison. Didn't understand your second question but the log file is printed with `type` command.

Comment: How can i trigger a command with this? thats my 2nd question.
(Im sure its a dumb question)

Answer (score 2):

wOxxOm already gave a solution to check for an updated file.

Here is a way to produce a Sound:

```
copy con bell.txt
```

Then press the ALT-key enter `007` while keeping ALT pressed, then release the ALT key. `^G` should appear on your Screen (= 0x07, which is a Bell), then press Ctrl-Z. This gives you a textfile with lenght = 1 Byte

```
Type bell.txt
```

will then beep.

**EDIT** an easier way to produce `bell.txt`: on commandline, enter `echo ^G>bell.txt` (to produce `^G` press `CTRL`-`G`). This will create a three-byte-file (instead of the one-byte-file with the `copy` trick) (but that's only a line feed and should not disturb).

Comment: Alternatively, you could put `ECHO ^G` into the .bat script. The "^G" is made by pressing Ctrl+G. Your editor might or might not cooperate in using control characters. Note that "G" is the seventh letter in the Roman alphabet.

Comment: Or embed a vbscript code that either prints `chr(9)` directly to the console or makes a temporary file with the character.