# Batch ping listener and crude data transfer

Tags: batch-file

As a project of personal interest I've been wondering if there would be some way to make a batch chat service. (I'm well aware of all kinds of alternatives, this more just a personal proof of concept, as I love finding unique ways of doing things.)

Now, the inbuilt messenger services for Windows, msg.exe and net send are no long available. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can tell, there are no longer any ways to send data from one IP to another through batch programming.

Or is there? I'm no expert, by any means. But it is still possible to ping other IPs through cmd. If it is possible for the pinged computer to reply (to state that it has pinged), then there must be an active listener. And if this listener is there, is it not then possible to code a batch program to transfer binary data through pings alone? E.g., it receives 1 bit per second (Or variable resolution based on your connection) based on if it were pinged within that unit of time or not?

I would love to be able to make a proof of concept of this extremely crude "Ping chat", but I'm not sure how I would access that "listener" to tell if I've been pinged.

Goal of this project is to make it in BAT format without downloading any third party scripts, so it would have to be using batch and default commands.

PS: Again, I know this is ridiculously crude and impractical, no need to remind me. It's just as an amusing proof of concept to theoretically circumvent the removal of the inbuilt functionality. Creating functionality that isn't otherwise there interests me greatly, such as when I made an online game client in Game Maker 8.1. There are better ways to do it, for sure. It just for personal amusement.

Much love, all!

Comment: Use a shared file. Use `waitfor` to synchronise.

Comment: Will this work across the internet or only over local network sharing?

PS: Can I please point out that it's been nearly 2 years since I last posted on here, and you were the first poster on both my last post 2 years ago, and this post now? That's some harcore stalking, bro. :P

Comment: Only on the network.

Comment: Looking for something over the internet, thus why I want to try to do it in pings. Is there a simple "listen" command to just check if your IP has been pinged?

Comment: I've never heard of anything in any language that can do that outside of Hollywood ridiculousness.

Comment: Thus why I'd like to make it, if possible. ;P
All I'd really need is a "listen" command to determine if my IP has been pinged in the last X amount of time.

Comment: See this: http://www.unixist.com/security/data-transfer-over-icmp/index.html. Basically you would use the `-n` (count), `-l` (size) and `-i` (time to live) / `-w` (timeout) parameters.

Comment: Not certain it's quite what I'm after, but I might see if I can recreate it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but I have written a chat batch script utility.that uses polling to detect new messages. It works well in my hands. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29967710/1012053